# How to set the name of a file/image on clicking 'Save Image As'

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page on which I am displaying various photos. Whenever a user clicks on 'Save Image As', I want to set a name by which the pic would be saved instead of saving the pic with the original name. How can this be done?

Comment: You have to do this on the server side.

Comment: Do you mean the "save image as"-function of the browser, that is displayed in the context-menu? AFAIK this function always uses the filename which is part of the url of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that using JavaScript.

The server needs to send a `Content-disposition` header containing the correct filename.

Answer (score 2):

if php:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```